# How do I mocha/chai test with a file argument?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I have a file normally run in the command line as

*node index.js myFile.bmp*

How do I start testing this with mocha/chai?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

create a file called index-test.js with the following contents:

```
var index = require('./index');

describe('index', function() {

// add your tests here
});
```

Comment: But index needs process.argv[2] to run. How do I account for that?

Comment: you can mock the argv, in a ``before`` method you can set the argv to something like this ``process.argv[2] = '..'``

Comment: Ideally you should extract the actual functionality that you run in index into another file that takes as parameters what gets set in argv, then you could test that file instead of index.js